# Global navigation with active selector (PHP)

Tags: php, html, css, navigation

Instead of repeating the navigation bar code in every page I want to write a single snippet of PHP code for the navigation menu bar and include that file in the relevant pages. My first HTML code of the navigation bar menu is as follows. (By default, "USERS" is selected.)

```
<ul>
   <li class="active" ><a href="administrator1.php"><span><B>USERS</B></span></a></li>
   <li><a href="administrator2.php"><span><B>CREATE PROFILE</B></span></a></li>
   <li><a href="administrator3.php"><span><B>PAYMENTS</B></span></a></li>
   <li><a href="administrator4.php"><span><B>DEFENSE</B></span></a></li>
   <li><a href="administrator5.php"><span><B>PROGRESS REPORT</B></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

So I changed the above code to a PHP Code. The file name having this code is 'test.php'

```
<?php
$menu = array(
    'users'          => array('text'=>'USERS',           'url'=>'?p=administrator1.php'),
    'createProfile'  => array('text'=>'CREATE PROFILE',  'url'=>'?p=administrator2.php'),
    'payment'        => array('text'=>'PAYMENTS',        'url'=>'?p=administrator3.php'),
    'defense'        => array('text'=>'DEFENSE',         'url'=>'?p=administrator4.php'),
    'progressReport' => array('text'=>'PROGRESS REPORT', 'url'=>'p=administrator5.php'),);

class Nav {
    public static function GenerateMenu($items) {
        $html = "<ul>";
        foreach($items as $item) {
            $html .= "<li><a href='{$item['url']}' ><span><B>{$item['text']}</B></span> </a></li>";
        }
        $html .= "</ul>";
        return $html;
    }
};
?>
```

In 'administrator1.php' i called the above function as follows;

```
<?php 
    include 'test.php';
    echo Nav::GenerateMenu($menu);
?>
```

My problem is, how can I put 'administrator1.php' as the by default selected menu list item and how to put the selected list item a CSS class?

The selected list item should have 'active' CSS class.

```
<li class="active" >
```

Comment: Why did you need to convert the **HTML** code to **PHP** code???You could definitely `include` the HTML file if you wished.

Comment: I want to convert it to a PHP code so that there will be only one file with the navigation menu code. So, if something is needed to be changed, i will have to edit only one code. And as i want to put the selected item a CSS class as `<li class="active">` just a HTML code will not work! I will need a PHP CODE!

Comment: so your concern is actually `<li class="active">`.

Comment: Yes, I want to put `<li class="active">` for the selected item and by default it should be for 'USERS' item.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the current script file name is part of the url that is being displayed in the navigation. If so, then assign `active` class to it.

```
foreach($items as $item) {

if(stristr($item['url'],__FILE__)===FALSE)
  {
    $html .= "<li><a href='{$item['url']}' ><span><B>{$item['text']}</B></span> </a></li>";
  }
  else
  {
    $html .= "<li class='active'><a href='{$item['url']}' ><span><B>{$item['text']}</B></span> </a></li>";
  }

}
```

Comment: I changed the urls of each array items of $menu as 'administrator1.php', 'administrator2.php' etc. But still class='active' won't work although the navigation bar works properly!